# Send Outlook Task Reminder Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook

I wish to send an email outlook task with reminder by using powershell, is that possible? The task similar as image below:
[image]

Is powershell built in function able to create this task instead of create a normal email using "new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage"? Any sample code/documentation to refer?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search brought up these

1. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/02/21/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-set-a-reminder-on-all-my-office-outlook-appointments/
2. http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/03/01/getting-things-done-outlook-task-automation-with-powershell/
3. http://www.amandhally.net/2013/08/08/powershell-and-outlook-create-calendar-meetings-using-powershell-function/

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not what the does. That is a .Net class as documented here.

[Mail​Message  Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=netframework-4.7.2)

To use PowerShell with Outlook, you have to use the Outlook Object Model (DCOM). There are lots of examples of using PowerShell with Outlook all over the web. Doing a search will bring those up for you.

Here is just one example of dealing with Outlook Tasks with a few other references for you.

[Managing an Outlook Mailbox with PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx)

[Getting Things Done – Outlook Task Automation with PowerShell](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/03/01/getting-things-done-outlook-task-automation-with-powershell)

```
## Add-OutlookTask.ps1 
## Add a task to the Outlook Tasks list 

param( $description = $(throw "Please specify a description"), $category, [switch] $force ) 

## Create our Outlook and housekeeping variables.  
## Note: If you don't have the Outlook wrappers, you'll need 
## the commented-out constants instead 

$olTaskItem = "olTaskItem" 
$olFolderTasks = "olFolderTasks" 

#$olTaskItem = 3 
#$olFolderTasks = 13 

$outlook = New-Object -Com Outlook.Application 
$task = $outlook.Application.CreateItem($olTaskItem) 
$hasError = $false 

## Assign the subject 
$task.Subject = $description 

## If they specify a category, then assign it as well. 
if($category) 
{ 
    if(-not $force) 
    { 
        ## Check that it matches one of their already-existing categories, but only 
        ## if they haven't specified the -Force parameter. 
        $mapi = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
        $items = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderTasks).Items 
        $uniqueCategories = $items | Sort -Unique Categories | % { $_.Categories } 
        if($uniqueCategories -notcontains $category) 
        { 
            $OFS = ", " 
            $errorMessage = "Category $category does not exist. Valid categories are: $uniqueCategories. " + 
                            "Specify the -Force parameter to override this message in the future." 
            Write-Error $errorMessage 
            $hasError = $true 
        } 
    } 

    $task.Categories = $category  
} 

## Save the item if this didn't cause an error, and clean up. 
if(-not $hasError) { $task.Save() } 
$outlook = $null
```

See also this module:

[Powershell and Outlook: Create a New Outlook Task using Powershell OutlookTools Module](http://www.amandhally.net/2013/08/14/powershell-and-outlook-create-a-new-outlook-task-using-powershell-outlooktools-module)
https://github.com/AmanDhally/OutlookTools